# Scheduled Toast notifications are dropped

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, uwp-xaml

I have a calendar app in which i sync the events, if an event has reminder then a local toast notification for the reminder is scheduled. If there are 100 events with reminders then 100 notifications are scheduled. I'm observing that some of the notifications are not being triggered. Does this notifier has a limit. Please help me with the best practice to schedule the notification in this scenario.

Comment: Are you using the ScheduledToastNotification class for scheduled toast notifications? If not, you can try to use ScheduledToastNotification to display toast notification at the scheduled time and you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.scheduledtoastnotification). If yes, can you show the code about how you added the ScheduledToastNotification? And do you set the same Id to the toast? That will make the toast mess, you can check it.

Comment: Yes @Faywang-MSFT I'm using ScheduledToastNotification  class to schedule the notifications. But I'm facing issue like the notification is not triggered for all the events. Is there any limit in using this class. Can i schedule it for bulk of events.

Comment: I set lots of notifications to test and it worked well. All of the notifications can be triggered. So can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduce?

Comment: Thanks Faywang. Let me check if I missed anything from my side. Although I check already. Will double check that and share a sample.

Comment: OK, I will check it as soon as possible after you uploading it.

Comment: {"The size of the notification group is too large.\r\n"} {"The size of the notification tag is too large.\r\n"} this is the issue. Do we have any size limit on group and tag string too. I read only Id has that limit * ScheduledToastNotification.Id)

Comment: From the [ToastNotification.Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.group) and [ToastNotification.Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.tag) documens, they limit to 64 characters from 15063.

Comment: Thanks @Faywang-MSFT But I'm having a eventid which is greater than 64 chars, which i'm setting it to tag, Is there any way to set this long eventid

Comment: If you need to use tag or group to uniquely identify a toast notification by your eventid, it's better to limit eventid to 64 characters.